# Can I use SafeHandle to manage GCHandle?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, interop, interopservices, safehandle

`SafeHandle` gives a very strong guarantee that [the resource it manages will eventually be released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=net-6.0#why-safehandle), even if an asynchronous exception occurs. Even `using` and `try finally` cannot guarantee that.

I am thinking to use this guarantee to free a pinned [`GCHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle?view=net-6.0), however, there seems to be no ready to use implementation of the `GCHandle` managed by `SafeHandle` in C#.

So I created my own implementation that looks like this:

```
public class ArraySafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private GCHandle _handle;

    public ArraySafeHandle(byte[] array) : base(true)
    {
        _handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        SetHandle(_handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        _handle.Free();
        return true;
    }
}
```

[This works](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/SplitSafeHandleQuestion/SplitSafeHandleQuestion/Program.cs#L56), however, I am concerned that nobody is using `GCHandle` in this way. Also, setting the `IntPtr` in a `SafeHandle` manually does not seem to be a common way to create the `SafeHandle` (see, for example, [this remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.SetHandle?view=net-6.0#remarks) in the official docs).

What is the correct implementation? Is it even a working solution to wrap `GCHandle` in `SafeHandle` or it can fail at any time?

Comment: "`SafeHandle` gives a very strong guarantee that the resource it manages will eventually be released, even if an asynchronous exception occurs. Even `using` and `try finally` cannot guarantee that." That's a completely false statement from beginning to end. `SafeHandle` is not any more safe than any other finalizable object, except where PInvoke is concerned (because the PInvoke marshaller holds the reference). You *must* use either `using` or `finally` to correctly release `SafeHandle`. So no, wrapping a `GCHandle` in a `SafeHandle` does not do anything except if you are using PInvoke.

Comment: I guess the real question is why you are using `GCHandle` in the first place, it's not normally necessary, except in some complex marshalling situations when high performance is required, because PInvoke pins blittable arrays anyway.

Comment: Thank you, @Charlieface! I have a function in a 3rd party C++ library that takes 2 pointers to 2 not necessary contiguous memory regions and fills them with data. The problem is that in my case the memory regions should be contiguous (so that I could work with result using only 1 array). It seems like the only way in C# to fill 1 array using the function that takes 2 arrays is [to use `IntPtr`s](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/SplitSafeHandleQuestion/SplitSafeHandleQuestion/Program.cs#L26-L28). So I have to "convert" managed `byte[]` into `IntPtr`, here the `GCHandle` appears.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like even if there was a good way to wrap `GCHandle` in `SafeHandle`, that wouldn't solve my original problem: apparently it is impossible to "split" `SafeHandle` into two...